# Different behavior with sed between Ubuntu and OS X

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to prepend a base URL to a set of `href` elements in a HTML string using `sed`.

The HTML string (single line):

```
<!-- helpers --> <li> <a href="form-helper/basics/">Form Helper</a> </li> <li> <a href="html-helper/icons/">Html Helper</a> </li> <li> <a href="modal-helper/basics/">Modal Helper</a> </li> <li> <a href="navbar-helper/basics/">Navbar Helper</a> </li> <li> <a href="panel-helper/basics/">Panel Helper</a> </li> </ul>⏎
```

My commands (`menu.html` contains the above string):

```
site_url='https://example.com'
menu=$(cat menu.html)
echo $menu | sed -E 's@</li>\s+@</li>\n@g' | sed -E 's@href="(.*?)"@href="'"$site_url"'/\1"@g'
```

This works fine on my Ubuntu machine, but on OS X it gives me the following error:

> sed: 1: "s@href="(.*?)"@href="fo ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Is there a way to make the above `sed` work on both Ubuntu and OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $menu | sed -E 's@</li>\s+@</li>\n@g' | sed -E 's@href="([^"]*)"@href="'"$site_url"'/\1"@g'
```

i think you try match chars not `"`, so replace `.*?` with `[^"]*`, it works on my MAC OS.

Comment: Thanks, this work for the second part, actually `"(.*)"` works on OS X, I don't know why...